# Checking a string to see if file exists locally

Tags: php

I have a question if I may. I have a variable named `$source` and this *should* contain a relative path to a file, for example `./uploads/2012/some-document.pdf`

Now, this `$source` variable will contain user input, via $_GET and $_POST. I don't want people to enter URLs and I only want to do something if the file exists **only** on the local server.

My question is what is the best way to check if a file exists on the local server only?

---

This is what I've got so far:

1) `file_exists` may return true depending on the server configuration, so I could use this alongside stripos to check if the first few charatcers of the string is http:// like so:

```
if( file_exists($source) && stripos($source,'http://')!==0 ) {
    echo 'File exists on local';
}
```

However, the downside would be I'd have to specify all the different URL types such as https://, http:// and ftp:// just to be safe.

2) I use `realpath` to get the absolute path of the file, and this returns false if it cannot be found. This seems to be pretty solid, but not 100% this is the best application for it

3) Use `preg_replace` to remove all URL mentions in the string first, and then simply use `file_exists`.  Whilst this would probably be the most secure, it would most likely be the most intensive and I'd prefer not to use this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you can deny paths that use a scheme simply with:

```
if (parse_url($path, PHP_URL_SCHEME)) {
    // has something:// so ignore
}
```

This would also work with specialty wrappers such as `php://`, `zlib://`, etc...

You can also force a local check on the input variable by prepending with `file://`:

```
file_exists('file://' . $path);
```

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion to use parse_url, I think that and file_exists would be good. Thanks

Comment: There can be issues under Windows using file_exists() and is_file() in combination with remote files. It seems like Windows is downloading it or something like that. Better use parse_url() and check for empty host.

Answer (score 2):

Go with `realpath()` (in conjunction with `file_exists`). It will filter out URLs for you, and you should get a solid reliable result on whether the file exists or not.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of combining those two, I think they will work well together. Cheers